# When I change page in Next.JS whole page gets updated. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using Next.JS for my SPA website in React.

- I configured routing (https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)
- And I also configured Layouts (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts)

My Layout includes , sidebar and footer.

My problem is that when I have `useEffect(() => { //SOMETHING }, []);` in my Layout component it gets called every time I change page with Next.js's `<Link>` or `router.push(path)`.

From my research, everything on page gets rerendered.

This should not be hapenning. Components outside of Layout should just receive update and not complete rerender. Only stuff inside Layout should get rerendered (same way as React Router) works.

What is causing this? Is it fixable or is it Next.js's by design.

Minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-ebdz5

Comment: Can you share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the relevant code you've an issue with? We can't help debug code we can't see.

Comment: @DrewReese https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-ebdz5

Comment: You're changing routes, so the components will re-render. What that layout pattern enables is state persistence, it doesn't prevent re-rendering.

Comment: State is not peserved... Random number is changing...

Comment: State is preserved, it just happens that the `random` variable is not into state in your code. Try moving it into a state variable, you'll notice its value will not change upon client-side navigations.

Answer (score 1):

In the minimal example for the `Layout` component you are creating a new `random` value each time the route/path/view changes and rerendered. This is an unintentional side-effect and is not an accurate method at all for determining what is being mounted/remounted or rendered/rerendered as it's ***not*** using any of the React component lifecycle.

```
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const random = Math.random(); // <-- side-effect!!
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>{random}</div>
      <div>
        <Link href="/about">About</Link> <Link href="/">Index</Link>
      </div>
      <main>{children}</main>
      <footer>
        Click on different page and observe that random number changs which
        means that layout component gets rerendered and reinitialized everytime.
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Click on different page and observe that random number changes which
> means that layout component gets rerendered and reinitialized every
> time.

This is a very false assumption/conclusion.

If at a minimum you place the `random` value into a React state

```
const [random] = useState(Math.random());
```

you'll clearly see it remains constant and never changes no matter how many times you navigate between `"/"` and `"/about"` links/pages. In other words, the state persists *exactly* as the docs claim.

In fact, if you take it a step further and also use a mounting `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Layout MOUNTED", { random });
}, []);
```

you'll see it only ever logs once with the `random` state value and never changes or logs again.

```
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const [random] = useState(Math.random());

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Layout MOUNTED", { random });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>{random}</div>
      <div>
        <Link href="/about">About</Link> <Link href="/">Index</Link>
      </div>
      <main>{children}</main>
      <footer>
        Click on different page and observe that random number changs which
        means that layout component gets rerendered and reinitialized everytime.
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit NextJS (forked)]